# Overriding a preselected biblatex style, and suppressing unwanted BibTeX fields

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to suppress printing data related to article issue and month by using `biblatex`, but the code below does not work for citations generated by `\mcite` (or `\mcitesupercite`), although it does for simple citations generated by `\cite`.

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%  
\clearfield{issue}%  
\clearfield{month}%  
}
```

Is there any simple way to allow that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using biblatex 2.0 and biber 1.0, try this:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
       \step[fieldset=issue, null]
       \step[fieldset=month, null]
    }
  }
}
```