# Clear fields in biblatex 2.7

Tags: biblatex, biber

I've used the command `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}` to prevent `biblatex` from printing the month of publication in the bibliography. This has worked fine at least until `biblatex` version 2.5 and `biber` version 1.5:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{lennon,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "I wrote great music",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Journal of Music",
    YEAR = "1978",
    MONTH = "10",
    PAGES = "15--27",
    VOLUME = "5"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{lennon}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

In `biblatex` version 2.7a and `biber` version 1.7, however, this command apparently has no effect anymore:

[image]

What do I need to do in the new version of `biblatex` to prevent printing the month of publication?

Comment: I don't know whether it is a bug or something new, anyway the workaround in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62917/27635) works for me.

Comment: The year part of `authoryear` labels incorporate dates as of biblatex 2.6. So if you want to ignore months and days everywhere (including sorting), you need to omit these from the source (as in the post karlkoeller links to).

Comment: Given the number of questions asked earlier on TeX.sX on how to prevent ``biblatex`` from printing months in the bibliography, it's reasonable to assume that this would be a desired feature. It would be useful if someone could spell out in plain words and provide a command for how to do that. The answer to the question karlkoeller links to includes things like ``datatype=bibtex``, which seems tailored to the OP's request, and not a general solution for how to suppress months in the bibliography.

Comment: @Sverre Your source file in the example uses the BibTeX format, so the post applies to your problem as well - (again) assuming you want to ignore days and months everywhere including sorting. The `\clearfield` approach is still relevant to all styles that don't use date labels.

Comment: I see in the ``biblatex`` documentation that ``bibtex`` is the default data type. Is it still necessary to specify ``datatype=bibtex``? I still don't understand why ``\clearfield{month}`` has no effect here. The documentation says that "A field cleared this way is treated as undefined
by subsequent data commands".

Comment: @Sverre AFAIK yes. PLK would be a better person to ask about the `datatype` option. Citation labels are constructed by the backend, so your have to delete the field at the source. I can totally see how all this is unclear, so I've suggested year-only labels here: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/148

Comment: It won't be necessary to specify `datatype=bibtex` for sourcemaps in biblatex 2.8+, that will be the default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, the field you should clear is `labelmonth`, not `month`. If you change the command to `\clearfield{labelmonth}`, it works. To fully clear months, you should clear both `labelmonth` and `month`. This is because authoryear styles use `labeldate=true` and therefore the `label*` fields are used as the sources for the various date fields.

`labelmonth` and `labelday` were added in 2.6 in order to mirror `labelyear` which is why you see the difference to 2.5