# Don't print year for online entries in biblatex 2.7

Tags: biblatex

With the new version of `biblatex` (probably implemented in version 2.6, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126261/9077), `ONLINE` entries are now printed with full dates, with that information taken from the `URLDATE` field. I would like to suppress that (so that it appears like it did in version 2.5).

I can add `\clearfield{labelmonth}` and `\clearfield{labelday}` to my preamble to suppress the month and the day, but I can't add `\clearfield{labelyear}`, since that will remove the year from all other entries in the bibliography as well.

What can I add to my preamble to suppress printing the year in `ONLINE` entries only?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes,filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{labelmonth}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{labelday}}
%\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{labelyear}}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Peace on earth",
    YEAR = "1972"}
@ONLINE{googletranslate,
    TITLE = "Google Translate",
    SHORTHAND = "Google Translate",
    URL = "http://translate.google.com/",
    URLDATE = "2013-08-01"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
I managed to read \cite{lennon1972} with the help of \cite{googletranslate}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear the field conditionally for selected type(s):

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{online}{%
    \clearfield{labelyear}%
  }{%
  }%
}
```

A complete example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes,filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{labelmonth}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{labelday}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{online}{%
    \clearfield{labelyear}%
  }{%
  }%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Peace on earth",
    YEAR = "1972"}
@ONLINE{googletranslate,
    TITLE = "Google Translate",
    SHORTHAND = "Google Translate",
    URL = "http://translate.google.com/",
    URLDATE = "2013-08-01"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
I managed to read \cite{lennon1972} with the help of \cite{googletranslate}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could redefine `labeldate` to ignore `urldate` in your preamble. This stops `urldate` from being considered when generating `labeldate`:

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
}
```