# Supressing some fields from biblatex footcite

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex in a beamer presentation and would like to show compact references in footnotes. I'm using `\footfullcite`, but the problem is that it prints all the fields usually expected in the bibliography section.

Since it's only a presentation, I don't want to waste space with page numbers, journal volumes or issues and a few other fields.

I sucessfully used `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` to supress isbn, doi and url, but it can't deal with other fields, like the ones I mentioned. I found some similar questions here like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32930/is-it-possible-to-suppress-a-specific-field-from-bibtex-bbl-in-biblatex) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187643/biblatex-how-can-i-suppress-some-fields-for-multiple-entry-types), but the methods suggested there also didn't work for me.

EDIT:

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
    @article{TurneyPantel2010,
     author               = {Peter D. Turney and Patrick Pantel},
     journal              = {Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research},
     pages                = {141--188},
     title                = {From Frequency to Meaning: Vector Space Models of Semantics},
     volume               = {37},
     year                 = {2010},
     }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=false, doi=false, uniquename=init}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    This is a citation\footfullcite{TurneyPantel2010}.
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This generates a footnote with:

P. D. Turney and P. Pantel. "From Frequency to Meaning: Vector Space
Models of Semantics". In: Journal of Articial Intelligence Research 37
(2010), pp. 141-188.

I want to have the following format:

[Author Names] [Title] In: [Conference or Journal] [Year]

Comment: It is possible; depending on the precise needs, there may be several ways to achieve what you want. Provide an MWE, including some representative bib entries, and a *very clear* specification of what must appear, what must not appear, and for what entry types.  The MWE is important, too, because it includes things like the 'bibstyle' and 'citestyle'.

Comment: See this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62917/8528); but change fields to `volume` and `pages`. Note that it is doing 'per-type' filtering (in that case for `@article`).  Should work for your "Conference" too, if you change what needs to be changed....

Comment: You can go down the route of deleting all fields you don't want temporarily as in karlkoeller's answer below, but you could also set up a new command that only prints those information you are interested in (instead of mutilating the `\fullcite` idea).

Comment: @moewe Could you explain how to do that exactly? I'm interested in that approach...

Comment: @tschoppi You would essentially declare a new command for that. If you are interested ask a new question (link back to this question to give reference). (You may want to look round first to see if there is some other answer that already does this).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answers you've mentioned use `\AtEveryBibitem`, which is used to append code to an nternal hook executed at the beginning of every item in the bibliography.

You instead need `\AtEveryCitekey`, which is used to append code to an internal hook executed once for every entry key passed to a citation command.

So, something like

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
\ifentrytype{article}{
    \clearfield{pages}%
    \clearfield{volume}%
}{}
}
```

permits you to clear the fields `pages` and `volume` at every citation of an `article`.

If you need it for all types of entries, simply use

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \clearfield{pages}%
    \clearfield{volume}%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
    @article{TurneyPantel2010,
     author               = {Peter D. Turney and Patrick Pantel},
     journal              = {Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research},
     pages                = {141--188},
     title                = {From Frequency to Meaning: Vector Space Models of Semantics},
     volume               = {37},
     year                 = {2010},
     }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=false, doi=false, uniquename=init}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
\ifentrytype{article}{
    \clearfield{pages}%
    \clearfield{volume}%
}{}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    This is a citation\footfullcite{TurneyPantel2010}.
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]