# Suppressing "translator" field in biblatex footcite

Tags: beamer, biblatex

How to hide "translator" field in BibLaTeX? I found a bit similar problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232287/supressing-some-fields-from-biblatex-footcite). MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
    style=verbose-ibid,sortcites,
    firstinits=true,        % change names to initials
    maxcitenames=99,        % maximal number of authors
]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{translator} \clearfield{year}}  % HOW TO SWITCH OFF "TRANSLATOR"?

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}    % switch off buttons on the slide bottom

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mylist.bib}
@book{roadrunner,
    author =    {Geococcyx californianus},
    title =     {Gregorian choir},
    translator =    {Muose, Mickey},
    year =      {2017}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mylist.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Aaa aaa aaa aaa\footcite{roadrunner}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The year is omitted by the command `\clearfield{year}`. But how to force `\clearfield{translator}` to work similarly?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clear a name field, use `\clearname{translator}` not `\clearfield{translator}`.