# How can I remove the title from \footfullcite without removing the title in the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex

I am making a laboratory journal with the `memoir` document class and I have a brief summary page for each months entries. On that 1 page, space will be tight so I would like to remove the `title` field from `\footfullcite`. However, I am only aware of ways to remove it across the entire document (e.g. `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{}`).

Is there a way in which I can remove the title only for the reference occurance contained within the footnote and the full title still be printed in the main bibliography?

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Article{Basl21,
  author   = {Basler, Sophie and Studer, Sabine},
  journal  = {Nat Chem},
  title    = {{Efficient Lewis acid catalysis of an abiological reaction in a de novo protein scaffold}},
  year     = {2021},
  pages    = {231--235},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Foo bar baz\footfullcite{Basl21}.
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

I looked in the `biblatex.sty` and `biblatex.def` files on the [`biblatex` GitHub page](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/tree/dev/tex/latex/biblatex) but couldn't see where `\footfullcite` was defined beyond this:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

I checked in the `numeric.bbx` style and `standard.bbx` files too and could not find how I could modify `\footfullcite`. Any tips on which files to look into for `cite` command definitions for the future would be appreciated too.

Comment: Note that the number you get to see in the bibliography has no connection to the footnote number of your `\footfullcite`. You can see this if you cite the same source several times. (Or in your case even if you cite several sources in an order that does not correspond to the alphabetical order in the bibliography.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic way to get rid of a field only in citations (and `\footfullcite` still counts as a citation - even though it basically replicates the bibliography entry) is with `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{<field>}}`.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Foo bar baz\footfullcite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Something like

```
 \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{}
```

is never a good idea, since `biblatex` will still attempt to typeset the title and will only realise there is nothing to print at a very late stage (and because there is an explicit check for that).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and both of your comments. I have a query over your final part of the answer, in my main documents (indeed every document where I use `biblatex`), I use `\DeclareFieldFormat` to eliminate or modify fields. Should I be using `\AtEveryBibitem` to set them instead? (Not for `\fullfootcite` but general `\cite` purposes in other documents). By way of example, I am using `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{eprint}{}`, is this what you mean by this is never a good idea?

Comment: @1ae1_NADPH `\AtEveryBibitem`+`\clearfield` would work, but I generally prefer a sourcemap as a more robust way of getting rid of fields (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62900/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141822/35864). You can even use `\pertype` to restrict to `@article`s if that is needed https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229428/35864.